# .NET 5 not found in MacOS (Monterey) though it is installed

Tags: macos, .net-5

I am trying to run a project I created on .NET 5 (on another machine) on my MacOS machine running Monterey 12.1 and I got this error:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (arm64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.20 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      6.0.1 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

I thought it was strange since I remembered having installed it previously, but proceeded and installed (SDK 5.0.404) it again. And got the same error.
Then went and run `dotnet --list-runtimes` and got the following output:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I am totally lost. It seems even though I am installing the whole SDK package and later on tried also just with the runtime installation, my machine refuses to see it as installed.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem a while back in MacOS where I had two separate installations of dotnet. Only one of them was in the PATH. I'd installed by downloading directly from the Microsoft site and another with brew.
Try running "which dotnet" from the terminal and it will show you where the installation that's in the PATH lives.

Comment: I just saw that the problem is that the SDK available to download from Microsoft site is x64, while for my M1 Mac I need the ARM64. Any idea where I can find the ARM64 installer for .Net 5? I can't seem to find it

Comment: (For reference, the download site. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0 MacOS lists x64, but not ARM64.)
The Mac I'm using has x64. I remember reading something about a compatibility issue with ARM64 on MacOS, but I don't know for certain if that's the reason.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that the only version available of .NET5 for Mac is x64, and there is no ARM64 version for that version. ARM64 for Mac is only fully supported since .NET6